# Error with linq join

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-sql

I try to join two tables and ended up with this error message.

> The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query.

and

> Error  12  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Here is the Code:

```
    var query = (from packagingMainCustom in this.Connection.Tbl_PackagingMaster_Main_Customs
                 join packagingMainSync in this.Connection.Tbl_PackagingMaster_Main_Codes
                     on new { packagingMainCustom.ID_Code, packagingMainCustom.ID_Version }
                     equals new {  packagingMainSync.ID_Code, packagingMainSync.ID_CurrentVersion }
                 select packagingMainCustom);
```

This linq query is working:

```
    var query = (from packagingMainCustom in this.Connection.Tbl_PackagingMaster_Main_Customs
                 join packagingMainSync in this.Connection.Tbl_PackagingMaster_Main_Codes
                     on new { packagingMainCustom.ID_Code }
                     equals new {  packagingMainSync.ID_Code }
                 select packagingMainCustom);
```

Therefore the error message could be related to packagingMainSync.ID_CurrentVersion and packagingMainCustom.ID_Version.

Here is the declaration of both properties:

```
//packagingMainCustom
private long _iD_Version;
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required()]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key()]
public virtual long ID_Version
{
    get
    {
        return this._iD_Version;
    }
    set
    {
        if(this._iD_Version != value)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("ID_Version");
            this._iD_Version = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ID_Version");
        }
    }
}

//packagingMainSync
private long _iD_CurrentVersion;
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required()]
public virtual long ID_CurrentVersion
{
    get
    {
        return this._iD_CurrentVersion;
    }
    set
    {
        if(this._iD_CurrentVersion != value)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("ID_CurrentVersion");
            this._iD_CurrentVersion = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ID_CurrentVersion");
        }
    }
}
```

the only difference between both is the `DataAnnotations.Key()` Annontations.

Why is the query above not working and what does the error message mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the members in the anonymous type more obviously the same:

```
on new { Code = packagingMainCustom.ID_Code,
    Version = packagingMainCustom.ID_Version }
equals new { Code = packagingMainSync.ID_Code,
    Version = packagingMainSync.ID_CurrentVersion }
```

The main change here is that the names now match, as does the order, as presumably do the types; that means that these are actually now the same anonymous type in both places (anonymous types are essentially defined by the combination of member-names, order, type and declaring assembly).